# Orbeon forms - clear dropdown label

Tags: orbeon

I have 2 dropdowns (country_1 and country_2) populate with countries. Both are required. If I choose value some in the country_1 dropdown, the country_2 dropdown should be cleared (value and label).

Example:

1. In the country_1 dropdown I choose something.
2. In the country_2 dropdown I choose something.
3. In the country_1 dropdown I change value. country_2 should be cleard.
4. When I validate form I get error on country_2 dropdown (so it seems that the value has been cleared).

I would like to in step 3 the country_2 will have empty label.

I have added value change action to country_1 dropdown, that should clear country_2 dropdown value and label.

Example form:
https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/bc71b6532f4faee1ec711105a2db00bb65995d80

Source code: https://gist.github.com/mmakos-profidata/9728f086da3abc7bd96af27c8d5a70b8

Error screen:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Moving your code to be inside the `<xf:model>` does the trick. I've updated your form on `demo.orbeon.com`, but in case it disappears, this is the snippet that I put directly inside the `<xf:model>`:

```
<xf:action event="xforms-value-changed" observer="c_country_1-control">
    <xf:action if="//c_country_1 != 'af'">
        <xf:setvalue ref="//c_country_2"/>
        <xf:setvalue ref="//c_country_2/@label"/>
    </xf:action>
</xf:action>
```

Comment: hey Alex, are you sure it should works? I have published this form (on https://demo.orbeon.com/), tested it and I got the same error as before.
I have tested it on my local environment (orbeon version 2019.1.0) and I got error too.
I also made sure the code is inside the <xf:model>. I have updated my question and added screenshot with error.

Comment: @m.makos My bad: I updated the code in my answer above. Instead of `.` to access the value of the first dropdown, you should use `//c_country_1`. In the form source, I also removed the Visibility conditions you had on the "value" and "label" fields you had on the 2nd line so we can see those values being reset.

Comment: hey Alex, still not work as I expect. It is not enough for me to clear "value" and "label" fields (these fields are only for show value changes). The label on the dropdown c_country_2 should be cleared too. I have edited my question and form, to simplified the problem.

Comment: Ah! The value is reset in the data, but the control incorrectly keeps the old value. This is a bug. I've created issue [#4731](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4731), and we'll shoot to fix it in time for the upcoming 2020.1.

Comment: @m.makos Here we go, the issue [#4731](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4731) is now fixed and will be included in 2020.1.