# Orbeon Forms - prevent Form Builder from override template in form

Tags: orbeon

I’m using Oberon forms version 2019.2 CE.
Let's say I have section:

```
<s_address>
 <s_address-iteration>
  <grid-address>
   <c_country label=""/>
  </grid-address>
 </s_address-iteration>
</s_address>
```

When I run form and add new repeat of this section, new repeat is create from this template:

```
<xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
                     id="s_address-template">
            <s_address-iteration>
                <grid-address>
                    <c_country/>
                </grid-address>
            </s_address-iteration>
</xf:instance>
```

Now, I want to add label also to field c_country in template. However when I do this and apply changes, Form Builder remove this label from template.

Is it possible to prevent Form Builder from this?

I can create custom template for s_address section with label, but this solution will be hard in maintain.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be related with this:

- [Orbeon forms - clear dropdown label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65127502/orbeon-forms-clear-dropdown-label)
- https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4731

I need to add empty label in template to the field, because I have functionality in form, that when user press button, form gets data from external service and feeds the fields with that data (when it is dynamid dropdown I set value and label). If I am not add empty label to the field, the label will not shows properly in situation, when user add new section repetition.

For now, I solved the problem this way: I create my custom template based on templet created automatically by Form Builder and I use it instead of the default. This solution works, but as I wrote earlier, it is hard in maintain.

Comment: Thank you for posting what worked for you. Now I understand that you populate that `label` attribute with a service. But who is using its value? (And I'm asking as I'm wondering if there isn't a simpler way to handle this.) -Alex

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking about. I will give an example from my form: user can fill address section by his own or can click button, that fill address fields with data downloaded from service. Address section has a lot dynamic dropdown fields (with search).

Comment: Got it, so that `<c_country label=""/>` element is bound to a dynamic dropdown with search? Then, when you add the a dynamic dropdown with search in Form Builder, the element in the instance should automatically get a `label` attribute. And I imagine it is in a repeated grid, since you have a template. While the template doesn't get the `label` attribute, as soon as you create a new row, at least by clicking on the "+" icon, the `label` is added. Are you seeing something different, or adding rows in a different way? -Alex

Comment: <c_country/> field is a dynamic dropdown with search (Service performs search set to 'Yes' and Service supports paging set to 'No'). 
This dropdown is inside the repeated section (grid is not repeated). 
For the first instance of <c_country label=""/> I can add empty label for this field (in model) and it works good. Problem occure, when user add another iteration.

Comment: When user add new row/iteration, form using template, but template has no label for field <c_country/>. That is the problem. After user add new row/iteration, the <c_country> field has no label, so if user click button to feeds the fields with that data, <c_country/> field's label will not set, because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for those additional details. I am wondering if you are seeing something different because you have a different version, or because I'm misunderstanding the situation. Using Orbeon Forms 2020.1.3, this is what I am seeing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-aJZFtvO9cw. You'll let me know if I am missing something!

Comment: As I wrote in my original post, I'm using Oberon forms version 2019.2 CE and this issue still occurs. I have checked on Orbeon Forms version 2020.1.3 and I can confirm that the error is not occures (orbeon automatically add label to dropdown field even if I use it in repeated section).

Comment: Got it, perfect then, and thank you for confirming that this is working with 2020.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

The templates are recreated by Form Builder, which explains why your changes disappear. If you need an additional `label` attribute on your `<country>`, adding it manually to the template isn't the way to go.

Now what the "right way" to go about it I can't tell, just based on the information provided above. It will depend on what that `label` attribute is used for, when you need it. (Feel free to add a comment below, with a description of your use case, an I'll do my best to follow-up.)